# Make this countdown restart when finished

Tags: javascript, countdown, repeat

```
$(function(){ 
    var response = [
       {"time":1491656400,"name":"Boss Event","img":"<img style='width:38px;height:38px;' src='http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/tibia/images/f/f4/Hellgorak.gif/revision/latest?cb=20081010165415&path-prefix=en'/>"},
       {"time":1491674400,"name":"Paintball Event ","img":"<img style='width:38px;height:38px;' src='http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/tibia/images/3/3d/Snowball.gif/revision/latest?cb=20080124055247&path-prefix=en'/>"}
    ];
    $.each(response, function(i, item, name) {
        var time = new Date(item.time*1000) ;
        $('#timer').append('<tr><td valign="middle">'+ item.img +'</td><td style="width: 213px;text-align:center;"><strong>'+ item.name +'</strong><br><span id="t'+ i +'"></span></td></tr>');
        $('#t'+i).countdown({
            until: time, 
            compact: true,
            format: 'HMS'
        });  
    });
});
```

So im using this as an "event timer" for my tibia server and I have to be honest, I have no idea how this works, I just want to ask for help, I figured out how to set for example 3 hours, but once it reaches 0 it just ends, is there a way to make it resart once it countdowns to 0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code, it's difficult to discern whether the epoch timestamp within the "response variable"  is what is terminating the jquery ".countdown".  If that is the case, after the countdown, redeclare the response variable with an added time to the epoch time, then recall the function.
  example-

```
function(){ 
          var time1 = currentTime.getTime()+3*60*60*1000; //time+3hrs
          var time2 = currentTime.getTime()+3*60*60*1000; //time+3hrs
//now, declare the new response items
          var response = [
      {"time":time1,"name":"Boss Event","img":"<img style='width:38px;height:38px;'src='http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/tibia/images/f/f4/Hellgorak.gif/revision/latest?cb=20081010165415&path-prefix=en'/>"},
      {"time":time2,"name":"Paintball Event ","img":"<img style='width:38px;height:38px;' src='http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/tibia/images/3/3d/Snowball.gif/revision/latest?cb=20080124055247&path-prefix=en'/>"}
      ];
      $.each(response, function(i, item, name) {  //loop through the countdown for each of the response items
        var time = new Date(item.time*1000) ;
        $('#timer').append('<tr><td valign="middle">'+ item.img +'</td><td style="width: 213px;text-align:center;"><strong>'+ item.name +'</strong><br><span id="t'+ i +'"></span></td></tr>');
        $('#t'+i).countdown({
          until: time, 
          compact: true,
          format: 'HMS'
        });  //end of the countdown
      });  //end for each of the response items 
//recall the function here
    });
```